# ownCloud Mac Client: csync failed to authenticate

Tags: macos, authentication, owncloud

Trying to get the ownCloud OS X sync client to work, but always receive this error:

> "csync failed to authenticate at the owncloud server"

I tried setting it up with and without SSL, but the error is the same. Anyone have any tips?

Using ownCloud Server 5.0.9, and OS X client 1.3.0

Comment: So did I ask a really bad question?

Comment: Is this the exact error message you see? Because I can't find anybody else seeing this message at the moment.
In general, for questions about owncloud you might also consider going to [the ownCloud forum](https://forum.owncloud.org/) or if you're sure it's a bug to its [issue tracker](https://github.com/owncloud/mirall/issues)